# What is the proper term for the methods defined inside of a Python class before the class is instantiated?

Tags: python, oop, class, function, terminology

Using this example from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects:

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

According to those docs, f is an attribute reference that returns a function object.

Is there any shorter way of saying what f is?  Can I call it a method of a class (note how I didn't say "class method" which is incorrect)?  Or a function defined within a class?  Or an instance method?

In other words, what's the formal short-hand term for f in terms of its relation to MyClass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referring specifically to the `f` returned by `MyClass.f`, then `f` is an **unbound method** of MyClass. Or at least that's what the REPL calls it:

```
>>> MyClass.f
<unbound method MyClass.f>
```

In general though, I don't think anyone would fault you for simply calling it a "method", plain and simple. Or, in terms of its relation to MyClass, a method of MyClass.

Comment: Or maybe a "MyClass method" -- in any case, people say "string method" or "list method" all the time.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's an instance method(or member function), because this method is only accessible when you bind it with an instance, `instance.f()` or `MyClass.f(instance)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = MyClass()
def __init__(self):
    self.data = []
print x.i
print x.f()
print MyClass.__doc__

# Instance x = MyClass()
# More __init__(self) is important
# Sorry my english. I'm from Brazl
```

Comment: You do not have to define an `__init__`.  The class definition in the original question is sufficient.